# red question mark loading image as texture with Firebase storage

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, texture2d, loadimage

I'm trying to load image from firebase storage, but all that I get is a red question mark in unity or even when I build the application in android this is my script that I use 
** I had a start function (start) to get all the data from firebase storage**

```
 private void Start()
    {
        const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("GoodAnswer.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
          ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
          {
              if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
              {
                  Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
              }
              else
              {
                  fileContents1 = task.Result;

                  Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
              }
          });
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("BadAnswer1.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
        ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                fileContents2 = task.Result;

                Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
            }
        });
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("BadAnswer2.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
       ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
       {
           if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
           {
               Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
           }
           else
           {
               fileContents3 = task.Result;

               Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
           }
       });
    }
```

**And this is the function I call when I click on load button**

```
 public void Load()
    {


        int height = 1024;
        int width = 1024;

        target1 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        target2 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        target3 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        //target.LoadRawTextureData(fileContents);
        //target.Apply();
        //target.EncodeToJPG();
        //imgLoad.texture = target;

        target1.LoadImage(fileContents1);
        target2.LoadImage(fileContents2);
        target3.LoadImage(fileContents3);



        imgLoad1.texture = target1;
        imgLoad2.texture = target2;
        imgLoad3.texture = target3;


        Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
    }
```

[image: picture]

this is what I get when I run my application on the editor or my android phone

**This is all my script to more understand my problem**

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Storage;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;

public class Gallery_EN : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public RawImage img;
    public RawImage img2;
    public RawImage img3;
    Texture2D texture;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storage_ref;
    Texture2D t;
    Texture2D tt;
    Texture2D ttt;
    private Texture2D target1;
    private Texture2D target2;
    private Texture2D target3;
    public byte[] fileContents1;
    public byte[] fileContents2;
    public byte[] fileContents3;
    public RawImage imgLoad1;
    public RawImage imgLoad2;
    public RawImage imgLoad3;
    void Awake()
    {
        UnityThread.initUnityThread();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://kataraproject-a233a.appspot.com");

    }
    private void Start()
    {
        const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("GoodAnswer.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
          ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
          {
              if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
              {
                  Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
              }
              else
              {
                  fileContents1 = task.Result;

                  Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
              }
          });
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("BadAnswer1.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
        ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                fileContents2 = task.Result;

                Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
            }
        });
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("BadAnswer2.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
       ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
       {
           if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
           {
               Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
           }
           else
           {
               fileContents3 = task.Result;

               Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
           }
       });
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void DoIt()
    {
        NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery((path) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
            if (path != null)
            {
                //  imagePath = path;
                // Create Texture from selected image
                texture = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath(path, 1024); // image will be downscaled if its width or height is larger than 1024px
                if (texture == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                    return;
                }
                img.texture = texture;
                t = TextureToTexture2D(img.texture);

                // Use 'texture' here
                // ...
            }
        }, title: "Select single image", mime: "image/*");




    }

    public void DoItt()
    {
        NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery((path) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
            if (path != null)
            {
                // Create Texture from selected image
                Texture2D texturee = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath(path, 1024); // image will be downscaled if its width or height is larger than 1024px
                if (texturee == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                    return;
                }
                img2.texture = texturee;
                tt = TextureToTexture2D(img2.texture);

                // Use 'texture' here
                // ...
            }
        }, title: "Select single image", mime: "image/*");

    }

    public void DoIttt()
    {
        NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery((path) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
            if (path != null)
            {
                // Create Texture from selected image
                Texture2D textureee = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath(path, 1024); // image will be downscaled if its width or height is larger than 1024px
                if (textureee == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                    return;
                }
                img3.texture = textureee;
               ttt = TextureToTexture2D(img3.texture);


                // Use 'texture' here
                // ...
            }
        }, title: "Select single image", mime: "image/*");
    }

    public void Upload()
    {



        byte[] custom_bytes1 = t.EncodeToPNG();
        byte[] custom_bytes2 = tt.EncodeToPNG();
        byte[] custom_bytes3 = ttt.EncodeToPNG();



        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        Firebase.Storage.StorageReference rivers_ref = storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img1.png");

        // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
        rivers_ref.PutBytesAsync(custom_bytes1)
            .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                }
                else
                { // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string download_url = metadata.ToString();
                    // string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                    Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);

                }
            });

        Firebase.Storage.StorageReference rivers_ref2 = storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img2.png");

        // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
        rivers_ref2.PutBytesAsync(custom_bytes2)
            .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                }
                else
                { // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string download_url = metadata.ToString();
                    // string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                    Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);

                }
            });

        Firebase.Storage.StorageReference rivers_ref3 = storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img3.png");
        rivers_ref3.PutBytesAsync(custom_bytes3)
           .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
           {
               if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
               {
                   Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                   // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
               }
               else
               { // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                   Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                   string download_url = metadata.ToString();
                   // string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
                   Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                   Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);

               }
           });



    }
    private Texture2D TextureToTexture2D(Texture texture)
    {
        Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D(texture.width, texture.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture renderTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(texture.width, texture.height, 32);
        Graphics.Blit(texture, renderTexture);

        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        texture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        texture2D.Apply();

        RenderTexture.active = currentRT;
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTexture);
        return texture2D;

    }
    public void Load()
    {


        int height = 1024;
        int width = 1024;

        target1 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        target2 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        target3 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        //target.LoadRawTextureData(fileContents);
        //target.Apply();
        //target.EncodeToJPG();
        //imgLoad.texture = target;

        target1.LoadImage(fileContents1);
        target2.LoadImage(fileContents2);
        target3.LoadImage(fileContents3);



        imgLoad1.texture = target1;
        imgLoad2.texture = target2;
        imgLoad3.texture = target3;


        Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
    }

}
```

anyone have any idea how to fix it, please

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out the problem I had to change my code to this

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Storage;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;

public class Gallery_EN : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public RawImage img;
    public RawImage img2;
    public RawImage img3;
    Texture2D texture;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storage_ref;
    Texture2D t;
    Texture2D tt;
    Texture2D ttt;
    private Texture2D target1;
    private Texture2D target2;
    private Texture2D target3;
    public byte[] fileContents1;
    public byte[] fileContents2;
    public byte[] fileContents3;
    public RawImage imgLoad1;
    public RawImage imgLoad2;
    public RawImage imgLoad3;
    void Awake()
    {
        UnityThread.initUnityThread();

        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://kataraproject-a233a.appspot.com");

    }
    private void Start()
    {


    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        int height = 1024;
        int width = 1024;

        target1 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        target2 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        target3 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img1.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
          ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
          {
              UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
              {
                  if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                  {
                      Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      fileContents1 = task.Result;
                      target1.LoadImage(fileContents1);
                      imgLoad1.texture = target1;

                      Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
                  }
              });
          });
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img2.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
        ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
        {
            UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    fileContents2 = task.Result;
                    target2.LoadImage(fileContents2);
                    imgLoad2.texture = target2;

                    Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
                }
            });
        });
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img3.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
       ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
       {
           UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
           {
               if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
               {
                   Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
               }
               else
               {
                   fileContents3 = task.Result;
                   target3.LoadImage(fileContents3);
                   imgLoad3.texture = target3;

                   Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
               }
           });
       });
        //target.LoadRawTextureData(fileContents);
        //target.Apply();
        //target.EncodeToJPG();
        //imgLoad.texture = target;












        Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void DoIt()
    {
        NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery((path) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
            if (path != null)
            {
                //  imagePath = path;
                // Create Texture from selected image
                texture = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath(path, 1024); // image will be downscaled if its width or height is larger than 1024px
                if (texture == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                    return;
                }
                img.texture = texture;
                t = TextureToTexture2D(img.texture);

                // Use 'texture' here
                // ...
            }
        }, title: "Select single image", mime: "image/*");




    }

    public void DoItt()
    {
        NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery((path) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
            if (path != null)
            {
                // Create Texture from selected image
                Texture2D texturee = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath(path, 1024); // image will be downscaled if its width or height is larger than 1024px
                if (texturee == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                    return;
                }
                img2.texture = texturee;
                tt = TextureToTexture2D(img2.texture);

                // Use 'texture' here
                // ...
            }
        }, title: "Select single image", mime: "image/*");

    }

    public void DoIttt()
    {
        NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery((path) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
            if (path != null)
            {
                // Create Texture from selected image
                Texture2D textureee = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath(path, 1024); // image will be downscaled if its width or height is larger than 1024px
                if (textureee == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                    return;
                }
                img3.texture = textureee;
               ttt = TextureToTexture2D(img3.texture);


                // Use 'texture' here
                // ...
            }
        }, title: "Select single image", mime: "image/*");
    }

    public void Upload()
    {



        byte[] custom_bytes1 = t.EncodeToPNG();
        byte[] custom_bytes2 = tt.EncodeToPNG();
        byte[] custom_bytes3 = ttt.EncodeToPNG();



        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        Firebase.Storage.StorageReference rivers_ref = storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img1.png");

        // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
        rivers_ref.PutBytesAsync(custom_bytes1)
            .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                }
                else
                { // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string download_url = metadata.ToString();
                    // string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                    Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);

                }
            });

        Firebase.Storage.StorageReference rivers_ref2 = storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img2.png");

        // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
        rivers_ref2.PutBytesAsync(custom_bytes2)
            .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                }
                else
                { // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string download_url = metadata.ToString();
                    // string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                    Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);

                }
            });

        Firebase.Storage.StorageReference rivers_ref3 = storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img3.png");
        rivers_ref3.PutBytesAsync(custom_bytes3)
           .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
           {
               if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
               {
                   Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                   // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
               }
               else
               { // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                   Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                   string download_url = metadata.ToString();
                   // string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
                   Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                   Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);

               }
           });



    }
    private Texture2D TextureToTexture2D(Texture texture)
    {
        Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D(texture.width, texture.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture renderTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(texture.width, texture.height, 32);
        Graphics.Blit(texture, renderTexture);

        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        texture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        texture2D.Apply();

        RenderTexture.active = currentRT;
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTexture);
        return texture2D;

    }
    public void Load()
    {


        int height = 1024;
        int width = 1024;

        target1 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        target2 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        target3 = new Texture2D(height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img1.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
          ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
          {
              UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
              {
                  if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
              {
                  Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
              }
              else
              {
                  fileContents1 = task.Result;
                  target1.LoadImage(fileContents1);
                  imgLoad1.texture = target1;

                  Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
              }
          });});
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img2.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
        ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
        {
            UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                fileContents2 = task.Result;
                target2.LoadImage(fileContents2);
                imgLoad2.texture = target2;

                Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
            }
        }); });
        storage_ref.Child(InputManager.ButtonName).Child("img3.png").GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).
       ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
       {
           UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
           {
               if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
           {
               Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
           }
           else
           {
               fileContents3 = task.Result;
               target3.LoadImage(fileContents3);
               imgLoad3.texture = target3;

               Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
           }
       }); });
        //target.LoadRawTextureData(fileContents);
        //target.Apply();
        //target.EncodeToJPG();
        //imgLoad.texture = target;












        Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Great to hear that you found the problem. Can you describe what you changed about the code, and why that fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(image.Width, image.Height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false, false);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
tex.LoadImage(ms.ToArray());
tex.Apply();
ms.Close();
```

Comment: Could you also add a few sentences explaining your code and how it answers the question? Explaining your rationale will help others to understand a lot better.